# No error is being shown in the code but rows are not being added to the table

Tags: c#, sql

```
public partial class add_dept : Form
{
    public add_dept()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
    DataSet1TableAdapters.deptTableAdapter dta = new DataSet1TableAdapters.deptTableAdapter();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "" && textBox4.Text != "")
        {
            dta.Fill(ds.dept);
            bool flag = false;
            for (int i = 0; i <= ds.dept.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if(textBox1.Text==ds.dept.Rows[i]["dept_name"].ToString())
                {
                    flag=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag==false)
            {
                dta.Fill(ds.dept);
                DataRow d=ds.dept.NewRow();
                d["dept_name"]=textBox1.Text;
                d["emp_no"]=textBox2.Text;
                d["location"]=textBox3.Text;
                d["project_no"]=textBox4.Text;
                ds.dept.Rows.Add(d);
                dta.Update(ds.dept);
                MessageBox.Show("ROW ADDED");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Department already exists");
            }
        }
    }
```

table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dept] 
(
    [dept_id]    INT          IDENTITY (100, 1) NOT NULL,
    [dept_name]  VARCHAR (25) NULL,
    [emp_no]     INT          NULL,
    [location]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [project_no] INT          NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([dept_id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: I tried to remove the tag from your head line to look like this "No error being shown in code but no rows being added into table" but the system tells me that the post contains almost only code and doesnt let me save this changes.... And the system is right, the question doesnt explain anything.

Comment: what is the value of your `flag` variable? Did you already debugged your code?

Comment: i hv debugged it bt it doesnt shw any error.... initial value for flag is false

Comment: the code contains only two interesting sections the first checks if the name already exists in the db and the second tries to add a new entry if the name is not already present. My questions was concerning the value of the `flag` variable after the check for uniqueness, hopefully clear now ;)

Comment: its false there also... even it shows the message "row added"... bt database is not updated

Comment: so basically this piece of code is the only relevant? `dta.Fill(ds.dept);
DataRow d=ds.dept.NewRow();
d["dept_name"]="some name";
d["emp_no"]="123";
d["location"]="some location";
d["project_no"]="42";
ds.dept.Rows.Add(d);
dta.Update(ds.dept);`

If so could you please provide a more focussed code example?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
d["emp_no"]=int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
```

instead of

```
d["emp_no"]=textBox2.Text;
```

for your integer columns??